# Rails 3.2.6 Error Message (Windows Install)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I installed the newest version of rails on my windows machine and when I attempt to create a new application I receive the following error message any ideas:

C:\Sites>rails new apexa
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:
12:in `expand_path': non-absolute home (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:12
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/cli.rb:15
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/bin/rails:7
        from C:/Ruby/bin/rails:19:in`load'
        from C:/Ruby/bin/rails:19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and found the answer [here](http://royontechnology.blogspot.com/2011_02_01_archive.html):

In short, reset your %HOME% environment variables (at least in the same command prompt) and try again.

```
set HOME=
set HOMEDRIVE=
set HOMEPATH=
set HOMESHARE=
```